# Implode with array with keys in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, csv

I need to write an array to a .csv file in PHP.

Example array:

```
$array = array(
    "name" => "John",
    "surname" => "Doe",
    "email" => "nowhere@nowhere.com"
);
```

By using `implode(",", $array)`, I get a result like this:
`John,Doe,nowhere@nowhere.com`

However, I need to also write the key of each element to the file.

The desired output is this:
`name:John,surname:Doe,email:nowhere@nowhere.com`

How would I achieve this?

Comment: Try [serializing](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) or [json encoding](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) the array.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this code:

```
$out = $sep = '';
foreach( $array as $key => $value ) {
    $out .= $sep . $key . ':' . $value;
    $sep = ',';
}
```

Comment: I really like your solution with `$sep` for avoiding the classic problem of the trailing comma after the final key-value pair.

Answer (score 1):

```
$csv = "";

foreach($array as $key => $data)
{
    // be sure to add " in your csv
    $csv .= '"'.$key.':'.$data.'",';
}

// and add a new line at the end
$csv .= "\n";

echo $csv;
```

Comment: This will add a newline after every key-value pair, which is not what Jack is asking for. Also, this will leave a trailing comma after the final key-value pair.

Answer (score 0):

The answers above outputs a trailing comma at the end. To correct this, I use the following function:

```
$array = array(
    "name" => "John",
    "surname" => "Doe",
    "email" => "nowhere@nowhere.com"
);
function implodeKV($glueKV, $gluePair, $KVarray){
    $t = array();
    foreach($KVarray as $key=>$val) {
        $t[] = $key . $glueKV . $val;
    }
    return implode($gluePair, $t);
}

echo implodeKV( ':' , ',' , $array);
// outputs  name:John,surname:Doe,email:nowhere@nowhere.com
```

http://phpassist.com/2dde2#2

Answer (score 0):

If you're using PHP 5.3+, then an anonymous function can make your code a lot cleaner, though a simple for loop has the best performance. (Using `array_walk` comes close though!)

I ran some tests with a few different approaches (using PHP 5.4.33):

```php
function makeArray(&$a) {
    $a = array();
    for($i = 0; $i < 100000; $i++) {
        $a[rand()] = rand();
    }
    return $a;
}

makeArray($array);
$before = microtime(true);
$result = implode(
    ",", 
    array_map(
        function($k, $v) {
            return "$k:$v";
        }, 
        array_keys($array), 
        $array
    )
);
$after = microtime(true);
$dur = $after - $before;
echo "Array Map w/ anonymous function: {$dur}s<br>";

makeArray($array);
$before = microtime(true);
function kv_func($k, $v) {
    return "$k:$v";
}
$result = implode(
    ",", 
    array_map(
        "kv_func", 
        array_keys($array), 
        $array
    )
);
$after = microtime(true);
$dur = $after - $before;
echo "Array Map w/ function: {$dur}s<br>";

makeArray($array);
$before = microtime(true);
array_walk(
    $array,
    function(&$v, $k) {
        $v = "$k:$v";
    }
);
$result = implode(
    ",", 
    $array
);
$after = microtime(true);
$dur = $after - $before;
echo "Array Walk w/ anonymous function: {$dur}s<br>";

makeArray($array);
$before = microtime(true);
$ff = true;
$sep = ",";
$out = "";
foreach($array as $key => $val) {
    if($ff) $ff = false;
    else $out .= $sep;
    $out .= "$key:$val";
}
$after = microtime(true);
$dur = $after - $before;
echo "Foreach loop w/ loop flag: {$dur}s<br>";

makeArray($array);
$before = microtime(true);
$out = "";
foreach($array as $key => $val) {
    $out .= "$key:$val,";
}
$out = substr($out, 0, -1);
$after = microtime(true);
$dur = $after - $before;
echo "Foreach loop + substr: {$dur}s<br>";
```

Results:

```
Array Map w/ anonymous function: 0.13117909431458s
Array Map w/ function: 0.13743591308594s // slower than anonymous
Array Walk w/ anonymous function: 0.065797805786133s // close second
Foreach loop w/ loop flag: 0.042901992797852s // fastest
Foreach loop + substr: 0.043946027755737s // comparable to the above
```

And just for kicks, I tried the for loop without correcting for the trailing comma. It didn't really have any impact:

```
Foreach loop w/ trailing comma: 0.044748067855835s
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
$array = array(
"name" => "John",
"surname" => "Doe",
"email" => "nowhere@nowhere.com"
);
foreach( $array as $key=>$data ) {
$output .= $comma . $key . ':' . $data;
$comma = ',';
}

echo $output;

?>
```